# JavaFX - Access fx:id from nested FXML

Tags: java, javafx, view, controller, fxml

So, this is my main FXML file, called 'Home.fxml':

```
<VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <fx:include source="MenuBar.fxml" />
   <Label alignment="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Welcome to MSMusic" textAlignment="CENTER">
      <font>
         <Font size="62.0" />
      </font>
   </Label>
    <fx:include source="PlayerElement.fxml" />
</VBox>
```

within that file i am including a music player element which has a label with the fx:id 'songTime', when i try to use 'songTime' within the Controller of Home.fxml i get a NullPointerException, because the fx:id from within a nested fxml doesn't seem to be useable. Is there a easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is generally bad practice to expose UI controls outside of the controller for the FXML file in which they occur.

You can inject the controller from the included FXML file into the controller for your `Home.fxml` file:

```xml
<VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <fx:include source="MenuBar.fxml" />
   <Label alignment="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Welcome to MSMusic" textAlignment="CENTER">
      <font>
         <Font size="62.0" />
      </font>
   </Label>
    <fx:include fx:id="player" source="PlayerElement.fxml" />
</VBox>
```

and in the controller for `Home.fxml` you can do

```
public class HomeController {

    @FXML
    private PlayerElementController playerController ;

    // ...
}
```

where `PlayerElementController` is the controller class for the `PlayerElement.fxml` file. This is described under ["Nested Controllers" in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers), but essentially just use a field whose name is the `fx:id` for the `fx:include` with `"Controller"` appended to it, so here `fx:id="player"` for the include allows you to inject the controller instance for the included FXML file to the field `playerController`.

Now just define some methods in `PlayerElementController` for setting the desired text:

```
public class PlayerElementController {

    @FXML
    private Label songTime ;

    // note: might want to make the parameter a more appropriate type than string,
    // and perform the conversion to a string in this method...
    public void setSongTime(String songTime) {
        this.songTime.setText(songTime);
    }

    // and similarly here for the return type
    public String getSongTime() {
        return songTime.getText();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now back in your `HomeController` all you need do is

```
playerController.setSongTime(...);
```

to set the text. If you need other functionality associated with the label, just define the appropriate methods corresponding to the behavior you need.

Comment: It seems quite magic to me, how does the Application know it is getting the  right controller, since there could be more than one instance of the PlayerElementController, right? The only thing this does is practically saying give me any PlayerElementController, at least thats what it looks like to me.

Comment: @ScriptKiddy It injects the instance created by the `FXMLLoader` when it loads the FXML file corresponding to that particular `fx:include`. If you had other `fx:include`s with the same file, they would have different `fx:id`s and hence the corresponding controllers would be injected to different fields. Just like injecting fields corresponding to UI elements, the mapping is via the `fx:id`. So no, there is no magic and it is not picking an instance arbitrarily.

Comment: Hm ok, gonna check it out later, thanks for the answer